# webpack bundle file is not being generated with no errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am new to react, trying to learn webpack configuration. I am using webpack4 for my project, however, after setting up webpack, the bundle files are not generated, neither the js file nor the html file and there is no error.

The output on the console says "compiled successfully". How do i fix this. I have been struggling for about a week and no online resource seems to give me what i want.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const paths = {
    DIST: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    SRC: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    JS: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js')
}

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.join(paths.JS, 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: paths.DIST,
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },

    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },

                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options:{
                            modules: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            localIndentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
                            sourceMap: true,
                            minimize: true,
                            camelCase:true
                        }
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [htmlPlugin],

    devServer: {
        publicPath: paths.DIST,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: port,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open:true,
        hot: true
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you using dev server? If so, webpack dev server put your files in memory, not your '/dist' directory.

Comment: Thanks but how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all path correctly, not have missing file.

```
src/js/index.js
src/index.html
```

make sure run webpack correctly to show log like:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --bail --progress --profile"
},
```

and run by `npm start`, then will show the log.

---

if you want, you can use new babel version. change your bable with this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.42",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.0",

    ...

    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "webpack": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13"
},
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

then update your webpack rule:

```
 {
    test: /\.js$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')]
      }
    },
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
```